# ChartJs - Line chart , Min value not being selected automatically

Tags: chart.js, min, linechart

I want to set a chart where the the min and max scales are selected accordingly to the data.

According to docs (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) this should happen automatically, unless `min` and `max` are defined.

However my chart is not setting max and min, even when the min is like 250 and max 265. I cannot really show the difference.

[image]

```
this.chart = new Chart($(divId), {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                //labels: labels,
                datasets: [],

            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{

                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            max: moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
                            min: moment(new Date(new Date().getTime()-(30*24*60*60*1000))).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
                            unit: 'day'
                        },

                        ticks: {
                            source: 'auto'
                        },

                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                    position: 'right',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 20,
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'x'
                }
            }
        });
```